# how to create pagenation in dynamic table view in android

Tags: android

```
PaginationLayout paginationLayout = new PaginationLayout(this);
        paginationLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    // creates content only for sample
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    table.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    table.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    table.addView(row);

    TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
    row2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    table.addView(row2);

    for(int i = 0; i< 50;i++){
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Button " + i);
        if (i%2==0) {
            row.addView(button);
        } else {
            row2.addView(button);
        }
    }

    // add the content in pagination
    paginationLayout.addView(table);
    // set pagination layout
    setContentView(paginationLayout);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is for Pagination better to use ListView instead of TableLayout. With ListView your data and UI will be managed by adapter easily.

See this example

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/PagingListView